# how to improve the search of the value by rank?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a package value:

```
{'1': 2, '2': 1,'6': 3, '3': 5}
```

this means:

```
{'1', '1', '2','6', '6', '6', '3', '3', '3', '3'}
```

I am doing this:

1. sort with key, so it becomes:`{'1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 5,'6': 3}`
2. get the Nth value. so if I want the 3rd value,it should return `'2'`

what I am doing is :

```
def getNth(scores, rank):
    scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

    total = 0
    for score, cnt in scores:
        total += cnt
        if  total > rank:
            return score
```

I want to know can I be fast?

Comment: Why do you think your code is slow? You might want to try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I know it has been o(n),but it do want to know can I be quicker?

Comment: The code is `O(n log n)`, because of the `sorted`. But if you want the order, then I would say your code is perfectly fine. You might want to convert the `key` function to return a number instead of string.

Comment: your code actually seems wrong, your code outputs 1,1,2,3 for ranking 1-4, what are you actually basing the rank on? I don't see the logic

Answer (score 0):

You can (based on my experiments below) halve the runtime if you simply don't regenerate scores here:

`scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))`

I created a modified method that avoids this:

```
def getNth2(scores, rank):
  total = 0
  for i in sorted(scores.keys()):
    total += scores[i]
    if  total > rank:
        return i
```

Measuring the runtime [here](https://repl.it/JbeG):

```
start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(0,100000):
  for i in xrange(0,10):
    getNth(d, i)
end_time = time.time()
print 'Old Runtime:', end_time - start_time

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(0,100000):
  for i in xrange(0,10):
    getNth2(d, i)
end_time = time.time()
print 'New Runtime:', end_time - start_time
```

> Old Runtime: 2.22607803345
>
> New Runtime: 1.09168481827